# Insert data into redis from kafka via redis-sink-connector by splitting the record key

Tags: apache-kafka, redis

Trying to find some reference to store kafka records into redis via `Kafka-Redis-Sink` connector by splitting records `keys` in following way

Example of Kafka records: \

```
<`key`> <`value`>                 ========> `expected redis operation` \
\<User1|state1|id1\> \<data\>     ========\> redis=\> hset "User1|state1"  "id1"  data \
\<User1|state2|id2\> \<data\>     ========\> redis=\> hset "User1|state2"  "id2"  data \
\<User2|state1|id3\> \<data\>     ========\> redis=\> hset "User2|state1"  "id3"  data \
\<User2|state2|id4\> \<data\>     ========\> redis=\> hset "User2|state2"  "id4"  data
```

So hash for user-state mapping will have all mapped ids and using `HGETALL` in redis for `User1|state1` all the ids and data can be retrieved.

---

```
`HGETALL` `"User1|state1"`

id1
data
id2
data
```

Comment: @AnkitSahay updated the question.

kafka records needs to be inserted in a redis hash map based on the key

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it a must to use kafka-redis-sink-connector or are you ok with using custom consumer application?

Comment: Sure, keys can be split with a custom transform. What have you tried?

Comment: @AnkitSahay,  Kafka-redis-sink-connector will be preferred.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I haven't tried custom transform. Any reference for custom transform for Kafka record keys to redis hash set(HSET)

Comment: You will need to write Java code. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html